# How do you make onClick parameters be saved per table row?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, render, semantic-ui

My code is using semantic UI table and written in ReactJS. In my render function, I have a table with rows and every row I call a onClick function where I pass in an item. However, the item passed in to the onClick is always the last item, perhaps because onClick happens after rendering. How do I make it so that each row passes the correct item into my onClick function?

```
    for (var item in props.items) {
            rows.push(
                <Table.Row
                onClick={() => {
                    handleClick(item);
                }}>
                    <Table.Cell><text className='tableEntry'>{item}</text></Table.Cell>
```

Comment: replacing `var item` with `let item` solves the problem. Itz a scope issue, you may need to read about closures and scope in js

Comment: @ajaiJothi Thanks alot! That worked, I'll go read up more on it thanks!